# CCLabelTTF::setString not accepting white space at start and end of string

Tags: c++, windows-phone-8.1, cocos2d-x-3.0, cclabelttf

I'm trying to set value of a label in cocos2d-x. It's not showing spaces if I add them on start or end of string, like

```
label->setString("10 10");
```

working correctly. But if I use

```
label->setString(" 10");
label->setString("10 ");
```

it only show "10" , spaces are trimmed.

Comment: It works in cocos2d-x version 3.4 final.  Spaces are not trimmed

Comment: I'm using it for windows-phone 8.1. Working fine for iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out the problem, `label->setString()` function is ok. Problem is with `label->getContentSize().width` , it does not include white spaces at start and end of string while calculating width of label(this problem occurs while working in windows phone 8.1).And labels were overwriting in my case because of incorrect positioning.